# Clicar em um link e exibir o valor dentro de um input

Tags: javascript

Olá, alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer isso, tenho 10 link, cada link corresponde a um elemento tipo `link 1 = :D, link 2 = :S, link 3 = :$` e assim por diante, ai eu tenho um `input type="text" name="mensagem" placeholder="digite sua mensagem..."/>`, minha dúvida é o seguinte, como eu faria pra quando a pessoa clicasse em um desses link o valor que é informado neles mostrasse no input? sem ser pelo `value=""`, vou exemplificar melhor `<a href="javascript:void(0)">:D</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)">:S</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)">:$</a>` ao clicar em um desses link quero que envie o valor correspondente ai link clicado para o `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `eventListener` com `click` para cada `<a>`, que ao ser clicado, o texto correspondente será concatenado ao texto do `input`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var els = document.body.querySelectorAll("a[href*='java']");
   
   for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
      
      els[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
         var a_txt = this.textContent,
              inpt = document.body.querySelector("#texto");
              
         inpt.value += " "+a_txt;
      });
   }

});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">:D</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">:S</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">:$</a>
<br />
<input id="texto" type="text" value="olá!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const 
    //O input
    input = document.getElementById('input'),  
    //Listener de quando clica
    clickListener = function(){
       input.value += this.innerText;
    };

document
   //a's filhos de .links-texto
   .querySelectorAll( '.links-texto a' )
   .forEach( function( e ){       
      //e = <a>
      e.addEventListener( 'click', clickListener );
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
<section class="links-texto">
  <a href="#">:D</a>
  <a href="#">:$</a>
  <a href="#">:)</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var els = document.body.querySelectorAll("a[href*='java']");
   
   for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
      
      els[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
         var a_txt = this.textContent,
              inpt = document.body.querySelector("#texto");
              
         inpt.value += " "+a_txt;
      });
   }

});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">:D</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">:S</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">:$</a>
<br />
<input id="texto" type="text" value="olá!" />
```